# ORA-31011: XML parsing failed while trying to get XML output

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g

When trying to get a value from an CLOB XML column, I get the following error:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: '/l-analysis/vehicle/odometer-reading/reading value/text()'
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

I have the following XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<l-analysis>
   <vehicle>
      <make>SAAB</make>
      <model>9000 CSI</model>
      <body-style code="SL">Saloon</body-style>
      <vehicle-type code="7">Passenger car/van</vehicle-type>
      <odometer-reading latest="true">
         <reading value="154267213">154267213</reading>
         <reading-date value="2006-07-17">17-Jul-2006</reading-date>
      </odometer-reading>
   </vehicle>
</l-analysis>
```

When trying to get the `reading value` value, I am running this query:

```
select XMLTYPE(xml_data).EXTRACT('/l-analysis/vehicle/odometer-reading/reading value/text()').getStringVal() AS XML FROM lm
```

I believe the error is due `reading value` having spaces? 'Cause for another XML column that doesn't have spaces it works.

How could I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is an attribute of `reading` not its text. To address an attribute of a node use `@<attribute name>`.

```
SELECT xmltype(xml_data).extract('/l-analysis/vehicle/odometer-reading/reading/@value').getstringval() AS xml
       FROM lm;
```